# Validation error messages without the attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to show custom error messages without the attribute name in front. I used to do this with the custom_error_message gem, however it doesn't work with Rails 3.1

What I'm trying now in create.js.erb:

```
alert("<%= @post.errors[:title] %>")
```

Which returns

```
[&quot;Here goes my custom message?&quot;]
```

My question is -- how can I remove the brackets and the &quot so only the message is left. I'll insert it into the page using jquery.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you want errors on a base object, not a particular attribute use:

```
errors.add(:base, "Here goes my custom message")
```

As for the brackets and quotes, I guess it depends how you're setting your errors.  When you just say `@post.errors[:base]` it will return an array.  This alert is just literally spitting out the array.  You'd probably want to iterate over the errors or just grab `.first` if there's only one.

Also, calling `.html_safe` will take care of the `&quot;` issue.

Comment: Much better framed answer than what I was typing.

Comment: What is a base object?